# Joomla TinyMCE Editor removes <link> from html

Tags: joomla, tinymce

My code is this:

When i toggle the editor I have:

Where have I got it wrong?

Comment: Maybe you enter the code again as the examples are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your title, I am assuming any <link> tag is being stripped.

Link tags are [only valid in the head of the page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html), and TinyMCE is set to use the HTML5 specification by default when it tidies code, so presumably it is removing them due to their invalidity in the body of the page.

You could probably configure the code of TinyMCE to do what you want (see: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_children), but as that does not seem to be possible via Joomla's plug-in parameters, it would mean overriding a core file, which may then cause problems should you patch the site.

One alternative would be to turn off Tiny MCE, and add the code via the blank editor.

Ideally, it sounds like you should be creating a bespoke module in which the link element can go in the head of the page as it should be.